# Remove a folder including the folder itself on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, mac

I want to recursively remove the folder `5`

If I gave the absolute path, it only removed the data under folder `5` excepting the folder itself.

But it worked if I gave the relative path.

How to fix it by absolute path ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that's the absolute path? From what I can tell, the absolute path is:

```
~/Dropbox/Rails/zeus/public/uploads/streaming_verification/excel
```

Thus, your absolute path `rm` command may need to look like:

```
rm -rf ~/Dropbox/Rails/zeus/public/uploads/streaming_verification/excel/5
```

The first `rm` command in your example seems to refer to a (confusingly similar) absolute path

```
/uploads/streaming_verification/excel
```

Can you check that this directory isn't a duplicate of the one in `public`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not doing it for me (using zsh - you didn't specify, but it should work in Bash):

# stib at editron in ~ [17:07:44]
$ mkdir test; cd test

```
# stib at editron in ~/test [17:07:51]
$ mkdir {1..10}            

# stib at editron in ~/test [17:07:59]
$ touch {1..10}/{1..10}    

# stib at editron in ~/test [17:08:05]
$ ls                       
1  10 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

# stib at editron in ~/test [17:08:19]
$ rm -rf 5                 

# stib at editron in ~/test [17:08:33]
$ ls
1  10 2  3  4  6  7  8  9

# stib at editron in ~/test [17:08:35]
$ rm -rf /Users/stib/test/6 

# stib at editron in ~/test [17:08:56]
$ ls
1  10 2  3  4  7  8  9
```